# парсинг xml файла с ftp сервера

Tags: java, android, xml, ftp, xmlparser

I can not implement parsing from ftp, and everything works with the folder on the phone.

Не могу реализовать парсинг с ftp, из папки телефона все работает.

```
    public void podcl() {

            try {

                Log.e("FTP", "Start ftp session");
                FTPClient mFTP = new FTPClient();
                Log.e("FTP", "FTP connection");
                mFTP.connect("*****");
                Log.e("FTP", "Provide FTP credentials");
                if(mFTP.login("*******", "******")){ Log.e("FTP", "I managed to connect to FTP");}
                mFTP.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                mFTP.changeWorkingDirectory("/ftp");
                Log.e("FTP", "The beginning of the stream");
                inStream = mFTP.retrieveFileStream("doc.xml");
```

1 вариант 
1 option

```
 InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inStream, "UTF8");
               BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
```

2 вариант 
2 option

```
  //  InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(new BOMInputStream(inStream, false, ByteOrderMark.UTF_8));
          //  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);

    Input = "";
                Log.e("FTP", "Reading file stream");
                do{Input = Input + reader.readLine() + "\n";}
    Log.e("FTP", reader.readLine());}while(reader.readLine()!=null);
               mFTP.logout();
               mFTP.disconnect();
            } catch (SocketException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch bloce.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();}
```

Насколько я понимаю, я здесь что-то не так делаю.
As I understand it, I am doing something wrong here.

```
XmlPullParserFactory xppf = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
 XmlPullParser parser = xppf.newPullParser();
  parser.setInput(new StringReader(Input));

                int eventType = parser.getEventType();

              //  switch (eventType){
                while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

                    if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

                        if (parser.getName().equals("vrachspi")) {.........
```

Ошибка такая
The error is this

> org.xmlpul.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT @1:2 in java.io.StringReader@c7f4db0)

кажется, это решается так
it seems to be solved like this

http://bighow.org/questions/22962078/simplexml-error-org-xmlpull-v1-xmlpullparserexception-unexpe

Но мне это не помогло (
but it did not help me (

Comment: Укажите язык программирования.

Comment: android studio 3 java

Comment: На данном ресурсе принято задавать вопросы на русском языке. Обновите свой вопрос

Comment: Добавил описание проблемы на русском